# .NET GridView - Can I do in-cell data bars (like Excel 2007/2010)?

Tags: .net, gridview

Does .NET's GridView provide any shortcuts to doing "Data Bars" like in recent versions of MS Excel? Alternatively are there ready-to-use any freeware libraries?

This is what the feature looks like in Excel:

http://i.imgur.com/uoPbO.jpg

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/08/07/data-bar-improvements-in-excel-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, For now .net not having any options like the data-bar in excel.

But try this [blog](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2007/09/26/dynamically-setting-a-gridview-cell-background/) you will get an idea about the dynamic background setting for gridview in .net. May it will point you in a way.